# Getting Contents & Centers of gg2plot stat_hexbin Histograms

Tags: r, histogram

To find the bin centers, I've tried gg2plot_build(), but the center-coordinates it provides are not what's plotted. In the below example there are several misplaced "o" symbols and some bins w/o a symbol on them.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000, 6, 2), y = rnorm(100000, 6, 2))
hexHist = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + stat_binhex(bins=15);
hexDat = ggplot_build(hexHist)$data[[1]]
hexHistFinal = hexHist + annotate("text", hexDat$x, hexDat$y, label="o")
hexHistFinal
```

I've also given `hexbin::hcell2xy(hexbin(dat$x, dat$y, 15))` a shot, but that's even further away from what's plotted.

I'm not sure how to go about figuring out what data is in what bin. (My ultimate goal is to take the data in a given bin, take the averages of a third and forth column in said data, and use *annotate* to superimpose said average on a hexagonal density histogram). I've been working on this since yesterday morning with no results. :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in ggplot2. When the text annotations are added, there are actually missing tiles (i used `geom_text` but the same thing happens with `annotate`):

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1492) # always do this when generating random data so the result is reproducible
dat <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100000, 6, 2), y = rnorm(100000, 6, 2))
hexHist = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + stat_binhex(bins=15);
hexDat = ggplot_build(hexHist)$data[[1]]

grid.arrange(
  hexHist,
  hexHist + geom_text(data=hexDat, aes(x=x, y=y), label="O"),
  ncol=2
)
```

[image]

The three "misplaced" `O`'s are not actually misplaced. The underlying tiles aren't being plotted for some reason. It does the same thing in the "new" ggplot2 (I tried it). This may be worth filing an issue on github.

Comment: On the actual data set I'm using, [some of the "o" symbols are shifted to one side](http://i.imgur.com/wNDHvrN.png), and some tiles don't have any at all. Do you think this is a separate issue?

Comment: any chance you can link to the data file (saved as an rda, perhaps)? I contribute to ggplot2 on occasion and can see what's going on better.

Comment: Certainly: [Here's the data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=39723527375322557149) in .Rda as requested, and [here's a script](http://pastebin.com/Cg7wW0BF) that generates the histogram. Also, since I've got your attention, you wouldn't happen to have any suggestions for the getting-data-from-bin issue, would you? ;)

Comment: Also, I'm pretty new to R, but if I can help with looking into anything—feel free to ask. I wouldn't mind diving into it, especially to solve a relevant problem.